# Pesquisa no SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint

Realizei a instalação do SharePoint Foundation 2010, na sequencia configurei o serviço de pesquisa. A partir disso as pesquisas funcionam apenas para o usuário administrador do farm. Verificando o ULS e EventViewer do windows não identifiquei nenhuma inconsistência. O que eu deveria fazer a partir daí.

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro geralmente ocorre porque o serviço de busca vai ter as mesmas permissões do usuário logado.

Ele agrega permissões do usuário logado com as dele próprio. Você deve encontrar o serviço no seu AD e adicioná-lo ao grupo *Windows Authorization Access Group*. Eu tenho o SP numa VM em inglês - se o SO estiver em português e você não o encontrar, eu procuraria por algo como "grupo de acesso de autorização do Windows".

Depois disso basta reiniciar o serviço.

Comment: Olá Renan, obrigado pelo retorno. Neste caso tenho uma problema, eu não tenho acesso ao AD da empresa.

Comment: Pesquisando na internet vi essa solução, inclusive na MS. Mas no meu caso será impossível.

Comment: @ThiagoFernandes encaminhe o problema pro pessoal do suporte então.